# Appended Javascript cells lose style and size formatting

Tags: javascript, append, html-table

I have an html table that is getting appended by a javascript function when `<body onLoad="appendTable('alphabetTable')">` The problem is that the appended cells seem to detach from the rest of the table, losing cell size they should inherit from the `<th>`'s in the `<thead>` region and dropping the border.

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/48X5M/

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Alphabet Table</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/table.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#alphabetTable {border:1px solid black;}
</style>
</head>
<body onLoad="appendTable('alphabetTable')">
<h1>Alphabet Table</h1>

<table id="alphabetTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Header1</td>
        <td>Header2</td>
        <td>Header2</td>
        <td>Header2</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function appendTable(id)
{
    var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    var alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
    var i = 0;
    for (var r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
        var row = tbody.insertRow(r);
        for (var c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            var cell = row.insertCell(c);
            cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(alphabet[i++]));
        }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(tbody);
}
```

The cells start appending at the `tbody` tag. Do I have to assign styles within the javascript? If so is there a way to avoid it for simplicity sake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're appending the tbody to the end of the page instead of appending it to the table. Taking the line `document.body.appendChild(tbody);` out fixes the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/Lajgn/

Your code ends up looking like this (JS and CSS removed for simplicity):

```
<body>
 <h1>Alphabet Table</h1>

 <table id="alphabetTable">
 <thead>
     <tr>
         <td>Header1</td>
         <td>Header2</td>
         <td>Header2</td>
         <td>Header2</td>
     </tr>
 </thead>

 </table>


 <tbody>
 <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr><tr><td>e</td><td>f</td><td>g</td><td>h</td></tr><tr><td>i</td><td>j</td><td>k</td><td>l</td></tr><tr><td>m</td><td>n</td><td>o</td><td>p</td></tr></tbody>
</body>
```

As you can see, the tbody ends up *outside* the table and winds up using default formatting.

Comment: Wow so much easier than I was expecting. That line was left over from a previous version I should have given it a harder look. Thanks!